# Changes to instance of a Class made by a tick() method aren't having a permanent effect

Tags: python, class, methods, namespaces, self

I am working on a game which involves a Vehicle class. It has mapx and mapy objects to record position, and a list of waypoints that also have x and y objects. Every tick of the game, I iterate over all Vehicle instances stored in a list and call a method, tick(), that should move the mapx and mapy values 1 closer to the x and y values of the first waypoint in the list. The code for the method is as follows:

```
def Tick(self,universe):
        print("tick vehicle")
        print(self.waypoint[0].__dict__)
        if self.mapx > self.waypoint[0].x:
            self.mapx -= 1
            print("L")
        if self.mapx < self.waypoint[0].x:
            self.mapx += 1
            print("R")

        if self.mapy > self.waypoint[0].y:
            self.mapy -= 1
            print("U")
        if self.mapy < self.waypoint[0].y:
            self.mapy += 1
            print("D")

        print("Vehicle:"+str(self.mapx)+","+str(self.mapy))
```

I have found that when the game runs, the mapx and mapy values of the Vehicle instance are not changing at all, despite all of the print() calls indicating that the right if/then statements are being followed. Is there a reason the tick() method can not change the properties of self?

Edit: Here is the full Vehicle Class:

```
import math

class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.waypoint = []
        self.systems = []

        self.mapx = x
        self.mapy = y

        self.hp = 200
        self.regen = 1

        self.holding = {
            "Iron" : 0,
            "Coal" : 0,
            "Nickel" : 0,
            "RareEarthMetals" : 0,
            "Copper" : 0,
            "Oil" : 0,
            "Soy" : 0,
            "Algae" : 0,
            "Steel" : 0,
            "Stainless" : 0,
            "Machinery" : 0,
            "Robots" : 0,
            "Biotech" : 0,
            "Electronics" : 0,
            "Microchips" : 0,
            "Plastic" : 0,
            "Wire" : 0,
            "ConsumerGoods" : 0,
            "Food" : 0,
            "FastFood" : 0}

    def Tick(self,universe):
        print("tick vehicle")
        print(self.waypoint[0].__dict__)
        print("Vehicle Before:"+str(self.mapx)+","+str(self.mapy))
        if self.mapx > self.waypoint[0].x:
            self.mapx -= 1
            print("L")
        if self.mapx < self.waypoint[0].x:
            self.mapx += 1
            print("R")

        if self.mapy > self.waypoint[0].y:
            self.mapy -= 1
            print("U")
        if self.mapy < self.waypoint[0].y:
            self.mapy += 1
            print("D")

        print("Vehicle After:"+str(self.mapx)+","+str(self.mapy))

        if (self.mapx == self.waypoint[0].x) and (self.mapy == self.waypoint[0].y):
            if self.waypoint[0].type == "temp":
                current = self.waypoint[0]
                self.waypoint.remove(current)
            elif self.waypoint[0].type == "looping":
                current = self.waypoint[0]
                self.waypoint.remove(current)
                self.waypoint.append(current)

        for system in self.systems:
            if (self.mapx == system[0].mapx) and (self.mapy == system[0].mapy):
                if system[1].action == "RX":
                    for planet in system[0].planetList:
                        if planet.storedCommodities[system[1].subject] > 0:
                            quantity = planet.storedCommodities[system[1].subject]
                            planet.storedCommodities[system[1].subject] = 0
                            self.holding[system[1].subject] = quantity

                if system[1].action == "TX":
                    quantity = self.holding[system[1].subject]
                    system[0].planetList[system[1].destination].storedCommodities[system[1].subject] = quantity
                    self.holding[system[1].subject] = 0

        for otherVehicle in universe.vehicleList:
            if math.sqrt( (otherVehicle.mapx - self.mapx)**2 + (otherVehicle.mapy - self.mapy)**2 ) <= 5: self.attack(otherVehicle)

        if self.hp < 200:
            self.hp += self.regen

    def attack(self,otherVehicle):
        pass#pew pew pew
```

Here is the main loop that is calling vehicle.Tick(self):

```
def Tick(self):
        for system in self.systemList:
            system.Tick()

        for vehicle in self.vehicleList:
            vehicle.Tick(self)
```

Comment: Add another `print` at the top of the function. I'll bet you'll find that the coordinates are changing, it's just that they're reset every time you enter the function. That would mean the problem is in the code you didn't show us.

Comment: Good catch, it is. Any thought as to what might cause this? The setup isn't terribly complicated, my main loop has a vehicleList list object. The vehicles are added by calling the constructor in a .append() call on the list. Then, while the game is ticking, each loop it calls `for vehicle in self.vehicleList: vehicle.tick(self)`

Comment: Why force us to try and guess? Provide a [minimal example](http://sscce.org) that recreates your problem.

Comment: Thats the odd part: when irecreate this setup in a minimal example, the problem doesn't occur. I added the full code, in case I'm not noticing that is affecting this.

Answer (score 0):

So, I am answering this question because, after quite a bit of investigation, I have figured out that the cause of these symptoms is an entirely separate problem that I don't think fits here. When I call `print(vehicle)` in the for each loop, it is a different memory address, despite being only one vehicle. I'm not sure if this is how Python is supposed to behave or not, returning a copy of the object instead of the object itself, but that is what has caused this problem.

**Edit: I am a huge idiot who did not realize that it made a *big* difference that my vehicle list was not an actual list, but a list manager from multiprocessing. Sorry for wasting your time.**